# Using the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma to find the integral of a very oscillating function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, oscillatory-integral

I'm a bit confused with how the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) is used to show that the integral of a very oscillating function approaches zero as the number of oscillation increases. To be more specific, let $f(x)=\cos(kx)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and zero everywhere else, and we want to find
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} f(x) {\rm d}x
\end{equation}
how does one use the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma to show that this definite integral approaches zero as $k \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Can you make more precise what you mean by $f$ being "very oscillating"? Without some concrete property it's hard to formulate an answer. Regardless, you should look into non-stationary and stationary phase, which gives estimates of oscilaltory integrals. The proofs rely on integrating by parts to obtain decay just like the proof of Riemann-Lebesgue.

Comment: @user293794, I've edited the question. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$. Then the Fourier transform of $f$ is given by
$$\hat{f}(k)=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-ikx}f(x)\,dx=\int_\mathbb{R}(\cos(-kx)+i\sin(-kx))\chi_{[0,1]}(x)\,dx$$
(perhaps also multiplying by $\pi$ somewhere depending on your convention). Thus, the real part of the Fourier transform of $f$, $\Re \hat{f}(k)$ is just equal to
$$\int_\mathbb{R}\cos(-kx)\chi_{[0,1]}(x)\,dx=\int_0^1\cos(kx)\,dx$$
where we have used that $cos(-kx)=cos(kx)$. The result then follows from the usual Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

However, I would suggest thinking about this result "by hand" by going back to the proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. The essence of the lemma is to use oscillation to obtain cancellation and thus decay. This situation occurs often in analysis and the usual way to make this precise is via integration by parts. In this instance, we would have to approximate $f$ by a smooth function close to it in the $L^1$ norm, and then proceed as in the proof of Riemann-Lebesgue.

Comment: Could you please expand on the first paragraph? If you are considering the Fourier transform of $\cos(kx)$ and use the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma to say that the transform approaches zero as $k\rightarrow \infty$, I do not see where the integral in $I(k)$ comes into play. (I'm a novice in Fourier analysis, sorry!)

Comment: Let me know if you still do not understand after the edit.

Comment: That is clear, thanks a lot! I see why you asked to clarify what I meant by "very oscillating" function. So, what sort of properties do the function needs to satisfy to generalize the result to "very oscillating" functions? I think infinite differentiability is enough? Is $L^{1}$ integrability enough?

Comment: I'm still not sure about what you're asking but maybe the following is enough: if $I(k)=\int e^{ikx}f(x)\,dx$ where $f$ is $L^1$ then the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma implies that $I(k)\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: hmmm...that is the statement in the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. What I'm trying to ask is what kinds of functions can be written as ${\rm e}^{ikx} f(x)$ so that we invoke the lemma to deduce that $I(k)$ vanishes as $k\rightarrow \infty$. Please direct me to a book or other resource if I'm missing the whole point here?

Comment: I don't really understand. If a function is written as $e^{ikx}f(x)$ and $f$ is $L^1$ then the lemma applies. It's not as if you can be presented with a function and not realize it is of the form $e^{ikx}f(x)$. Maybe a better thing is to ask what happens if you consider $\int e^{ik\phi(x)}f(x)$ for $\phi(x)$ a different phase function. This leads into the territory of oscillatory integrals see https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247b.1.07w/notes8.pdf for instance.

Comment: To give a context, I have a highly oscillating numerical error (oscillation increases with mesh refinement), but I don't have a closed form expression for the underlying error function. And thus, I don't know whether the function can be written as ${\rm e}^{ikx} f(x)$. I think the notes you shared will be a good starting point to understand the problem. Thanks a lot for the help! You have been awesome.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask another question with your particular error function in whatever form you have it.